# Delete a Value if it is not contained in another Column, in R

Tags: r

My Initial Data:

```
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c(NA,1,2,13,2,NA,6,10)
Data <- data.frame(From,To)
```

I want to change the Value from "To" to "NA" if the Row leads to a not existing "From".
The final Data should finally look like this.

```
From <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
To <- c(NA,1,2,NA,2,NA,6,NA)
Data <- data.frame(From,To)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a few ways

```
Data$To[!Data$To %in% Data$From] <- NA
Data$To <- ifelse(Data$To %in% Data$From, Data$To, NA)
Data <- within(Data, To[!To %in% From] <- NA)
Data <- transform(Data, To = ifelse(To %in% From, To, NA))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(Data)[!To %in% From, To:= NA]
```